# Discord js voice channel name not changing

Tags: database, asynchronous, async-await, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot that should change voice channel names according to the activity the users have inside the voice Channel.

```
 sync function updateChannelName(vChannel){
    const highestActivity = getMostImportantActivityName(vChannel.members)
    const name = await findOrCreateVoiceChannel(vChannel)                               // get name or create db entry if not exists

    // --- No activity in channel ---
    if(highestActivity == null){

        // Set voice to old name
        try {
            await vChannel.edit({name: name})
                .then(newChannel => console.log(`Channel name changed to ${name}`))
                .catch(error => console.error("Couldn't change name. ", error));
        } catch(error){
            console.error(error);
        }

        return;         // Leave function
    }


    // --- Activities in channel ---
    const newChannelName = await createNewChannelName(vChannel.guildId, highestActivity);

    // Set voice to activity name
    try {
        await vChannel.edit({name: newChannelName})
            .then(newChannel => console.log(`Channel name changed to ${newChannelName}`))
            .catch(error => console.error("Couldn't change name. ", error));
    } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
    }
   
}
```

This is the function that is called when the voice state changes inside a voice channel. `findOrCreateVoiceChannel` will connnect to a db and return a name. `getMostImportantActivityName` is returning a name

It always works like two or three times in a row and then stops working at all. I have heard about a rate limit to change voice names but I don't get any error whatsoever.

Debugging step by step worked as well. Even changing the name to a string didn't work after a few times.

All seems to lead to a rate limit but why is there no error when executing it?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this with moving members across channels. It sometimes worked then it didn't.
What I was told is that discord or discord.js doesn't handle channel related stuff the same as everything else, normally everything would work by just putting `await` in front of it but with channels its different.
What I did to fix this was adding a `new Promise` around it. So when you change anything channel related it would look something more like this:

```js
// Set voice to old name
try {
    await new Promise.all(vChannel.edit({name: name})
        .then(newChannel => console.log(`Channel name changed to ${name}`))
        .catch(error => console.error("Couldn't change name. ", error))
    );
} catch(error){
    console.error(error);
}
```

I don't know how to specifically apply this to your code so I don't think this example would work, but try some variations of that.

Just for extra reference; here is the piece of code I had to apply it to:

```js
for (const v in details.voiceChannels) {
    const vc = await guild.channels.cache.get(details.voiceChannels[v]);
    if (!vc) continue;
    await Promise.all(vc.members.map(async (member) => {
        if (member.voice.channel.id == vc.id) {
            if (details.autoQueuePlayers.includes(member.id)) {
                await member.voice.setChannel(autoQueueVC).catch(console.error);
            }
        }
    })).catch(console.error);
    await vc.delete().catch(console.error);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help but it didn't work. I think the answer was just the rate limitation but instead of an error the setName request will just be queued.

Comment: This got me too. I found it a pretty poor developer experience to give no guidance at all on this. I've got promises hanging around for minutes on end because the `await` never comes back with a response it just gets held... (seemingly indefinitely; at least 10 minutes).